# How I can manually adjust the brightness value of the camera?

Tags: iphone, ios

First, I'm sorry, I can not speak English well.
This translator is written

When I start the camera, it will automatically adjust the brightness.

How I can manually set the brightness value of the camera?

Answer (score 0):

You cant adjust brightness of camera in your code. Please follow the apple docs for available options for Camera controller/ ImagePicker Controller Programming guidelines.

Hope it helps.

[Link to Apple Doc is here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html)

Comment: Thank answer Do not manually adjust the screen brightness of support?(Do not flash)